# Jquery find match form entries

Tags: jquery, forms, field, match

I have a form that has multiple input fields in columns.

When a user enters an ID into a field, I want to check if another field has the same ID entry.

I'm doing this using **focusout** and looking at all fields with the matching class except the field I'm currently leaving.

This is what I have so far:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>ID</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type='text' name='uid[]' id='uid' class='uid' value='213'></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='text' name='uid[]' id='uid' class='uid' value='456'></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='text' name='uid[]' id='uid' class='uid' value='951'></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>


$('input[class="uid"]').focusout(function () {
    var check = ($(this)).val();

    $('input[class="uid"]').not($(this)).each(function(index){ 
        var test = $(this).val();
        if (check = test) alert('Match'); 
        });
 });
```

I've created a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3xk6Lfpu/)** that shows this.

The issue I have is MATCH is shown for each entry, not only for matching entries.

What have I done wrong ? How do I check for a match using the value from the field I've just edited against all other fields of the same class. ?

Also is it possible to highlight both matching fields ? and then clear them once they are no longer matching ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `===` for comparison instead of `=`.

Also,

```
  $('input[class="uid"]').not($(this))
```

can be replaced with

```
$('.uid').not($(this))
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xk6Lfpu/1/)

Comment: Thanks that seems to work great. It is possible to highlight both matching fields ? original post updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `==` for a comparison.

But than you got an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just change single '='  to '==' . you will get the result.